# Alternative of setClipToOutline for api level before 21

Tags: android, api

I need to clip an image behind a border image which is non linear. I have successfully tested setClipToOutline for this purpose but as setClipToOutline was introduced in api level 21, app crashes on devices before api level 21. Please suggest any alternative for this.

Comment: Found any alternatives?

Comment: did you found any solution?

Comment: no still no success.