# Circular image: alternative to setClipToOutline for pre 21

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-imageview

I am seeking a way to create circular images **without** 3rd party libraries.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773490/alternative-of-setcliptooutline-for-api-level-before-21) post that asked the same but had 0 answers.

In APIs post/equal to 21 (5.1), I use`setClipToOutline` method on a view ([because there is a bug where `android:clipToOutline` isn't working in the XML](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=164125)) and add a circular shaped drawable as background to the `ImageView`, but the app must support version 19 (4.4) onwards.

Is there any feature that allows me to achieve this? Maybe, in the support library?

Thanks.

Comment: did you found out any solution?

Comment: @FebinMathew Nope. I would suggest you to create a custom `ImageView` so that you don't have to handle different versions

Comment: @JonZarate found an answer?

Comment: @EladBenda Eventually moved to other projects / jobs.